# What is a good measure of correlation between stocks in an equity portfolio?

Tags: correlation, covariance

I am trying to analyse the degree to which the stocks in the MSCI AC World index are correlated with each other. As there are thousands of stocks in the index, I would like a single measure of correlation between the stocks.

Comment: One option would be to consider implied correlation indicies https://www.cequra.uni-muenchen.de/download/cequra_wp_14.pdf

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get the correlation matrix of returns then analyze its eigenvalues, e.g. look at the largest eigenvalue, which can be that one number you're interested in. See http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/001316448104100102?journalCode=epma or similar writings. If you're familiar with PCA, then it's the first principal component and associated with it explained variance.

Comment: I like this approach. However, why wouldn't I just calculate the mean correlation of the correlation matrix like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkRNSIAMoQg?

Comment: What if you have many neg elements?

Comment: What if you squared the elements in the correlation matrix and just averaged those? _Ceteris peribus_, I would end up with a number higher if correlations between the stocks were high and lower if they were low. This would suit my needs, since I just want to look at the correlation levels _relative_ to different time periods.

Comment: Average absolute correlation coefficient is a measure too, but I don't know if it has a strong intuitive power like eigenvalue